# Reference to function is ambiguous

Tags: c++, function, overloading

Why is this cause a compiler error, stating that my references are ambiguous? I have a `float`, `int` and `string`, which should all create separate function signatures, right?

Here is what I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int plus(int a, int b);
float plus(float a, float b);
string plus(string a, string b);

int main(void)
{
    int n = plus(3, 4);
    double d = plus(3.2, 4.2);
    string s = plus("he", "llo");
    string s1 = "aaa";
    string s2 = "bbb";
    string s3 = plus(s1, s2);
}

int plus(int a, int b) {
    return a+b;
} // int version

float plus(float a, float b) {
    return a+b;
} // float version

string plus(string a, string b) {
    return a+b;
} // string version
```

Comment: In this call double d = plus( 3.2, 4.2 ); which function do you expect to be called with floats or ints?

Comment: Which lines are causing the error?

Comment: @Barmar On `int n = plus(3, 4);`
    `double d = plus(3.2, 4.2);`
    `string s = plus("he", "llo");` and `string s3 = plus(s1, s2);` all function calls to plus.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

First, **don't use `using namespace std;`**. In this case, there happens to be a struct called [`std::plus`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/plus)—oh, wait, never mind, that's actually called `plus` and its constructor is thrown into the bucket for overload resolution with your function called `plus`.

---

Second, you have an ambiguity because `3.2` and `4.2` are of type `double` and can convert equally well to `float` or `int`.

This is a simplification, but when it comes to passing numbers to an overloaded function, C++ basically uses these rules:

1. If all the arguments exactly match one of the overloads, then use that one.
2. If all the arguments can be promoted to match one of the overloads, then use that one.
3. If all the arguments can be numerically converted to match one of the overloads, then use that one.

If you have multiple candidates at a specific level, then that is an ambiguity. Crucially, a `double` does not promote to a `float`—that would be a downgrade. So it has to use a standard conversion to a `float`, which ties with the standard conversion to an `int`, so those two overloads are ambiguous.

Answer (score 4):

Call the float overload like this:

```
double d = plus(3.2f, 4.2f);
```

A constant like 3.2 actually has type **double**.

Comment: For some reason though, i still get the same errors.

Comment: What compiler are you using? It solves the problem for me on VC++ 2010.

Comment: It conflicts with `std::plus`, but I used g++ and clang.